# Building a login form

Tags: django

I'm building a login form in Django and as far as my research about it goes is seems like I can't create login form that is "independent" from admin interface. What I mean by that is visitor doesn't have to be registered user in admin. Much like in PHP and MySQL. I can do what I need with PHP but I've been learning Python for some time now and would like to build it in Python. Is Django really gives me this only option ?

Makes me wonder how Pinterest did this. I know vast majority of the app is built in Django and people are presented with a login form on front page.

Comment: you mean you want to the user to signup then login in your website?

Comment: You got right my friend. Without having to be an user in admin.

Comment: I understand that Django is very advanced framework that still being worked on and developed. It kinda strikes me that this particular task isn't made without having to mess with admin.

Comment: oh, So you are new to django, ok django comes with the functionality of creating users(Signup) and authenticate them(Log in), there is a lot tutorials for this but i think the best for signup is [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) and for login use [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)

Comment: @mohammedqudah  I'll give it a go but it looks awfully similar to what I already have  :) I'll have a look through it in case I missed something important.

Comment: you said awfully, what was your problem

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact login views that are independent from the admin login, [as per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views):

Add the following to your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

This will include the following URL patterns:

```
^login/$ [name='login']
^logout/$ [name='logout']
^password_change/$ [name='password_change']
^password_change/done/$ [name='password_change_done']
^password_reset/$ [name='password_reset']
^password_reset/done/$ [name='password_reset_done']
^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$ [name='password_reset_confirm']
^reset/done/$ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

These provide views to login/change and reset passwords/etc for non-admin users. As a safety precaution, they do not include a sign-up view by default (since many implementations may want to not allow random people to sign up).

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful. I didn't write all the explanations, so please search for the attributes or methods you're not familiar with. Also, this implementation lacks many options like confirming the email address, etc. (these are secondary priority at the moment for me).
'password' and 'username' are model attributes in this case.
Here, after the user creates an account with a username and password, it is authenticated and the user is logged in then redirected to the specified url.

For html/bootstrap login forms, have a look at these:
https://bootsnipp.com/search?q=login

For the django implementation you can follow these steps:
1) After making the html form, add proper url line the urls.py

2) Make a new file in your project and name it forms.py, then:
from django import forms

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelsForm):
  email = form.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput) 
  password = form.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

  class Meta:
    model = *write your model name here*
    fields = *fields from your model. The model design should include 
             username email password and other attributes*
```

3) In views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

class UserFormView(View):
  form_class = UserForm
  template_name = *your html template*

  def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

  def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
      user = form.save(commit=False)
      username = form.cleaned_data['username']
      password = form.cleaned_data['password']
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save()

      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
      if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(*your redirecting url*) 
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

Comment: You really need to go through the basics of django and understand how it is constructed. It offers some powerful ways to handle such things. There are many and good online resources as well, just do a thorough search on the topic.

Most importantly, you have to be patient and dedicate quite a long time and go through the official documentation.